# Regex - Print the lines starting with a T

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I've a text file with some lines and I want to print the lines that starts with a T.

This works and gives the desired ouput:

```
f = open("path", 'r')
for line in f:
    match = re.search(r'^T', line)
    if match:
        print line
```

But this is not working as expected, it prints an empty list `[]` instead of an array containing the lines starting with T:

```
f1 = open("path").read()
print re.findall(r'^T', f1)
```

Where's the mistake in the 2nd solution?

Comment: You need [`re.MULTILINE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.M) for `^` to match the start of *lines*, not just the start of the *string*.

Comment: `print re.findall(r'(?m)^T', f1)`

Comment: ^ which does the same thing, but makes the flag part of the regex rather than an argument to the method

Comment: @AvinashRaj `print re.findall(r'(?m)^T.*', f1)` is the correct answer. Thanks for the tip, but what is `(?m)`?

Comment: Your code works on my machine. Are you sure that you actually have lines that start with an upper case T? Also, how is it possible that an empty list is being printed, when `line` is a string and not a list? Are you sure this is the exact code that you're actually running?

Comment: @Kevin because unless the first line starts with a `'T'` the expression doesn't match anything. It's only the second version that gives an empty list.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Can you post a solution with `re.MULTILINE` ? I dont know how to fit it on my code.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I would agree with you if they were doing `re.search(pattern, f.read())`... But it looks like they're searching line-by-line already

Comment: @Kevin they're effectively doing `findall(pattern, f.read())`; it's only the first version that iterates over the file line-by-line.

Comment: Oh, OK. I misread the question as "But [the code above] is not working as expected"

Comment: Here is [some code](https://ideone.com/NGTO21) illustrating the use of `re.M` modifier.

Comment: What is better to use, `re.M` or `(?m)^T.*` ?

Comment: It is the same modifier, one is inline, another is a non-inline version.

Comment: @Borja *"better"* how? I find the former more readable, but that's just an opinion and I doubt there would be any difference in performance.

Comment: Why not just do `if line[0] == 'T'`?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Because I'm learning regex :)

Comment: I have seen a good comment today: masteriing a tool also means knowing when not to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `^` to match the start of each line, rather than just the whole string, you need to use the [`MULTILINE` flag](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.M). You can either do this in the regex itself:

```
re.findall('(?m)^T', ...)
```

or as the `flags` parameter:

```
re.findall('^T', ..., flags=re.M)  # M is an alias for MULTILINE
```

Note that this will *only* give you the `'T'`s - to include the rest of the line in the matches you need to add e.g. `.*` to the pattern.

A quick demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = """Here is some demo text
This line starts with a T
But this one doesn't
That's OK"""
>>> re.findall('^T', text)
[]  # no multiline match, no results
>>> re.findall('^T', text, re.M)
['T', 'T']  # multiline match, only T in the results
>>> re.findall('^T.*', text, re.M)
['This line starts with a T', "That's OK"]  # hooray!
```